# Dynamics CRM Plugin - LINQ Query in 'Pre Validation'

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a Dynamics CRM Plugin registered in "Pre Validation" and trigger on delete.
I have inside it a LINQ query that retrieve the maximum value of a date field of children records for a particular parent record.

Here is my code:

```
var q = (from e1 in serviceContext.CreateQuery<entity1>()
       join e2 in serviceContext.CreateQuery<entity2>() on e1.typeid.Id equals e2.codeId
       where e1.statecode == 0 && e1.ParentId.Id.Equals(new Guid(ParentGuidStr))
       orderby e1.dt descending
       select new {e1.dt, e2.code}).ToList();
```

I am getting the following error on the above query When the record that the plugin triggers on is INACTIVE:

> PreValidateEntity1Delete PlugIn Error:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentNullException:
>   Value cannot be null. Parameter name: g

I am NOT sure why I am getting the above error and if the link between an inactive children record and a parent record got broken in a LINQ query or there is another reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please ensure all children records have reference to parent record.
Then, change your where contidion into:

```
where e1.statecode == 0 && e1.ParentId != null && e1.ParentId.Id.Equals(new Guid(ParentGuidStr))
```

The problem is that an EntityReference field (`e1.ParentId`) may be null and when you tried access a null entity, the error appears.

Then because of that, you should also make sure `e1.typeid` is not null in the join condition too.

Or, you can try a workaround with 2 separate queries, and collect information from their results.

Good luck!